# Trying to split a user input string by its spaces

Tags: java

Trying to split out a string and output the penultimate word inputted by the user, but the .split() only seems to be outputting a single string into the array so its not working?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Random_Exercises_no60 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
        String sentence = sc.next();
        String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println(words.length); // Just to check the array
        System.out.println("Penultimate word " + words[words.length - 2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is not with the `split` method, rather you should use `nextLine` instead of `next`:

```
String sentence = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: But the problem with nextLine is If we want to take two inputs its skips the first input and takes the second input. That's what I am facing now if I am using next so split not working and if I use nextLine so it's not taking first input

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Aomine should resolve your problem.  If you really wanted to use `Scanner#next()` directly, then you could also try setting the scanner's delimiter to be newline:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\r?\\n"));
```

Then, calling `Scanner#next()` should default to returning the next full line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the whitespace regex

```js
str = "Hello spilt me";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

The split is working correctly. Reading of information from console is correct. Below changes should work.

```
public class Random_Exercises_no60 {

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
    String sentence = sc.nextLine();
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");

    System.out.println(words.length); // Just to check the array
    for (String currentWord : words ) {
    System.out.println("The current word is" + currentWord);
}
}}
```